# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' in Aspose

Tags: php, aspose, comexception, aspose.words

I'm working with [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) API, `.NET Components` platform `Aspose.Words for .NET` product.

Here is my `test.php` code,

```
<?php
                //this is working correctly 
                $word = new COM("word.application");

                //return error in here
                $helper = new COM("Aspose.Words.ComHelper");
                $builder = new COM("Aspose.Words.DocumentBuilder");
                $license = new COM("Aspose.Words.License");
?>
```

when i run this it's return this error,

[image]

here is my vision information,

- WAMP server 2.5
- Apache 2.4.9
- PHP 5.5.12
- .NET Framework 4.6.1

what is wrong. can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the following article to work with PHP and Aspose.Words.

[PHP and Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/PHP+and+Aspose.Words+for+.NET)

You can configure your PHP to work with COM. Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php for more information. Also please read [Using Aspose.Words for .NET via COM Interop](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Use+Aspose.Words+for+.NET+via+COM+Interop).

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.